# How to reduce space around line numbers before every line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

How can I reduce the space around the line numbers?

[image: there is a photo]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide the line numbers?

Comment: i want to reduce (may be even remove) spaces around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomly found a solution.
RMB on line numbers, there will be option "lightbulb margin". off to remove those indents.

Comment: Does not work for me in VS 2022 Community. Whole right-most area in editor (C#) does not have any RBM menu.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable "Inheritance Margin".
At Visual Studio, CTRL+Q and type "Inheritance Margin".
At Options, unmark "Show inheritance margin" (at the bottom).

[image]